# Why am I getting undefined as an answer when fetching data from an API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I learning how to use fetch API and I am trying to print a quote from the Simpsons API as practice. The problem is that keep getting undefined as an answer. Do you know why it is not just printing the quote?

```
let button    = document.querySelector('#button')
let quote      = document.querySelector('#quote')

function getInfoFetch(){

  fetch('https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {

      quote.innerText = data.quote;

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInfoFetch)
```

Comment: `data[0].quote` - because data in this case is an array

Comment: That should be an answer :P.

Comment: I did, then I realised that 3 seconds of debugging is all it would take to fix such a basic issue @zozo - so I deleted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data of second `.then` is an array with a object inside.
If you want to get `quote` in the object, you need to use `data[0]` to select the object.Then, use `.quote` to select the key `quote` in the object. And you can get the value you want.

```
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
let quote = document.querySelector('#quote');

function getInfoFetch(){
  fetch('https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data); 
      //this is an array with object(index = 0) inside [{...}]
      quote.innerText = data[0].quote;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInfoFetch);
```

Answer (score 2):

The API's response appears to be an array, which means you'll need to need to access the quote data from say, the first item of the array response.

You can do that by making the following change to your code:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#button')
let quote = document.querySelector('#quote')

function getInfoFetch(){

  fetch('https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    
      // Access first item of data "array" to retrieve and display quote
      quote.innerText = data[0].quote;

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

button.addEventListener('click', getInfoFetch)
```

```html
<button id="button">Get quote</button>
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data which you are parsing is of Array type

```
[{"quote":"I can't even say the word 'titmouse' without gigggling like a schoolgirl.","character":"Homer Simpson","image":"https://cdn.glitch.com/3c3ffadc-3406-4440-bb95-d40ec8fcde72%2FHomerSimpson.png?1497567511939","characterDirection":"Right"}]
```

So to read that you need to pass index as well

```
fetch('https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {

      quote.innerText = data[0].quote;

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcsy2pfx/)